# Exceptions with prepare statement in java for a mysql update

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I have the following string:

```
public static final String UPDATESONG = "update songs SET " +
        "name = ?, artist = ?, albumName = ?, genre = ?, " +
        "time = ?, trackNum = ?, year = ?, numlikes = ?, numdislikes = ? where song_id = ?";
```

I then use the following code to prepare and use this statement:

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement(AppConstants.Queries.UPDATESONG);
        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.setString(2, artist);
        ps.setString(3, albumName);
        ps.setString(4, genre);
        ps.setInt(5, time);
        ps.setInt(6, trackNumber);
        ps.setString(7, year);
        ps.setInt(8, numberOfLikes);
        ps.setInt(9, numberOfDislikes);
        ps.setInt(10, id);
        ps.executeUpdate();
```

When I run my Junit test I get the following error:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your  SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right   syntax to use near 'time = 240, trackNum = 11, year = '2007', numlikes = 0, numdislikes =   0, where s' at line 1

It seems like the prepared statement is adding a , before the where clause. I think this is the cause of the issue, but I am not sure why it is showing up. Anyone have any insight to this issue?

**Edit:** I corrected the issue of the missing comma after genre=? and am still having the issue. Thanks for pointing that problem out though.

The error I am getting after adding the new comma is:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'time = 240, trackNum = 11, year = '2007', numlikes = 0, numdislikes = 0, where s' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:382)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3603)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3535)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1989)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2150)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2415)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2333)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2318)
at SongDAO.updateSong(SongDAO.java:155)
at SongTest.testUpdateSong(SongTest.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: I added the comma after genre=? and am still having the issue.

Comment: Does it show the same message? `... near 'time = 240 ...` indicated the missing comma.

Comment: @Thomas Yes sir, the error remained the same after I added the comma.

Comment: Is it just the same exception or the very same message? Please post it again and before you do check you actually recompiled the code (I had issues with code not being recompiled while I thought it was all too often).

Comment: @Thomas I recompiled the code and updated my question. I included the full trace, but I am not sure if there is more it can tell us. Thanks for the continued help.

Comment: Did you try to manually execute the SQL in some console (with the values inserted)? Does it work there?

Comment: @Thomas I did. It is updating properly. It seems weird to me that in the error there is a comma before where. I am not inserting that anywhere and if it is there, the MYSQL will not work. Any idea why that is showing up?

Comment: It's maybe just a bug in the message. Can you verify that other prepared statements using a where clause work?

Comment: @Thomas I have several others with where clauses that work properly. I went ahead and just made it a %s & %d string and just did string.format. This other method worked. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: @PFranchise, how did you use string.format to solve your problem? I am facing this same exact scenario.

Comment: @AbuZubair I apologize, but I no longer have this code. It was for a class project and unfortunately, I do not have the code any longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"name = ?, artist = ?, albumName = ?, genre = ? "` the last comma is missing.

Your SQL would be like `... , albumName = ?, genre = ? time = ?, trackNum = ?, ...`

Comment: Thanks! I actually just noticed that too, but I am still having the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a comma after `genre = ?` and before `time = ?`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma after setting genre.

```
  public static final String UPDATESONG = "update songs SET " +
    "name = ?, artist = ?, albumName = ?, genre = ?, " +
    "time = ?, trackNum = ?, year = ?, numlikes = ?, numdislikes = ? where song_id = ?";
```